# How can I create getter and setter for vector in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I declared `vector<test*> test1;` as a private, and I'd like to create getter and setter for this. I tried,

```
void setV(vector<test*> test1)
{
    test1 = test1;
}

vector<test*> getV()
{
    return test1;
}
```

It works, but it works very strange. Is there another way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Please explain that strange behavior

Comment: It is very hard to explain but it didn't add any data even if I use push_back. So I debugged it and I figured out when I declare like that, it goes ~vector() { _tidy(); }.

Comment: Hey, downvoters. Calm down. I've seen much worse questions here.

Comment: omfg..how do you expect anybody to help you? I don't understand why it is difficult to ask a proper question. Let's say you're a car mechanic. What do you say if somebody says "my car drives, but in a strange way". What if you're a dentist: "my tooth is still there but in a strange way". Yes, you don't say such unspecified stuff.. why do it in computer science?? tsssss...

Comment: Ah,, OK I'm sorry. My bad :( 
I'll try my best to give you proper question now :)

Comment: Also, white space is only ignored by compilers. Humans do tend to like wasting time reading judiciously applied amounts of it.

Comment: @duedl0r Calm down, dude. The question is not _that_ bad.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look at the assignment statement in `setV`:

```
test1 = test1;
```

The private variable `test1` is shadowed by the function parameter of the same name, and you're assigning that parameter to itself.

You should define `setV` like this:

```
void setV(vector<test*> const &newTest1) {
  test1 = newTest1;
}
```

That way you're really assigning the parameter to the private variable, and using a `const` reference for the parameter avoids an  unnecessary temporary copy.

---

Also, you should define `getV` as `const`, and returning a `const` reference:

```
vector<test*> const &getV() const {
  return test1;
}
```

That way it can be called on a `const` instance of your class, and it avoids making an unnecessary copy for the return value.

(You can also define another `getV`, without the `const`s, if you want the caller to be able to modify the vector of a non-const instance of your class.)

Comment: Thank you! Then getV has no problem?

Comment: @jcarlos, I amended the answer with some notes about `getV`.  It isn't *wrong* the way it is now, but it could be improved.

Comment: @MagnusHoff, I think using a separate variable name is a little clearer, but it's a matter of personal preference.

Answer (score 2):

In coupling with the earlier response, you'll also want to turn your getter into a pass-by-reference (as a pass-by-copy can be slower):

```
const vector<test *> &getV(){return test1;} //This will provide a read-only reference to your vector.
```